# How to do a SSL MITM for all programs trying to access the internet on my local Ubuntu

Tags: tls, linux, man-in-the-middle, ubuntu, network-access-control

How to do an SSL MITM for all programs trying to access the internet on my local Ubuntu.

When a program on my local machine tries to access the internet using https I would like to intercept and switch out the SSL Cert with a different SSL cert. I only want this to happen for specific websites and web APIs and I would like to match different SSL cert with different sites.

For instance, git tries to access https://example.com/foo.git I would like to say any program that tries to access https://example.com switch out https://example.com cert and return a custom cert to the program instead. If it is a different site I would like to switch to a different SSL Cert.

I looked everywhere trying to find something that will do this with no luck. Any help would be great thanks!

p.s. I do not mind building my own using node.js/python/java/c++ if someone points me in the right direction to the how to get started and what all I need to do...

Comment: Set up a proxy on your network. Provide the proxy's self-signed certificate as a certificate authority on your machines. Set up a firewall on your router that disallows all traffic except the traffic that goes through your proxy.

Comment: @Ghedipunk This would not do what I want. I would like to match a website with a custom SSL cert. when any traffic tries to reach out to a specific site I would like to switch out the returned cert with the custom one for only that site. i.e. program foo tries to access site "A" I ignore it and let it pass but when foo tries to access site "B" then I switch out the ssl cert.

Comment: With current versions of HTTPS, the domain name is not transmitted until after TLS is established.  If you want to read traffic for site B, then you have to be able to read traffic for A as well.  You might be able to do what you want by watching all DNS traffic and only replacing certificates for IP addresses that match site B, but if B and A have the same IP address, you'll also intercept traffic for A on your proxy.

Comment: @Ghedipunk Is there any node.js/python/java/c++ libraries that would let me setup a local proxy then monitor and conditionally switch out TLS/SSL certs?

Comment: It's also possible to get the domain name from the certificate, if you don't care to have your proxy watch your DNS traffic... But again, if the IP serves both A and B, you can't tell which was requested until the browser sends its HTTP header _after_ the TLS connection is established.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here.  There might be such, but I don't know of them, and if you edit your question to specifically ask for libraries, the question will be closed as off topic. -- However, you'll get better results from proxy applications rather than libraries in specific programming languages.  There are probably a few in Ubuntu's main repos.

Comment: My end goal is not to try and hide my traffic but only to manage apps on my local system. Some apps expect different Certs then what will be given for the site they are looking for.

Comment: @Ghedipunk+ all modern browsers, and most but not all other HTTPS clients, have been sending ServerNameIndication (SNI) for at least 5 years or so. (For other SSL/TLS protocols SNI usage is more varied.) And for programs that (can) use an explicit rather than 'transparent' proxy, the CONNECT verb has always (since before 2000) specified the target host. Tim: a few minutes googling finds instructions to intercept HTTPS for only some hosts using burp charles fiddler mitmproxy zap; I'm sure there are more, but product recommendations are offtopic :-?

Comment: I would except an answer that explains how to do this... Does not necessarily need to recommend tools or libraries. So far it sounds like I need to make some type of local proxy that all my local traffic goes through, then monitor it... If anyone knows what it would take to accomplish what i want that would be good enough for me...